# Magit set upstream to origin/master automatically

Tags: magit

Is there a way to set the upstream of a branch automatically in `magit`?

I know I can select it interactively but for feature branches I set it to `master` 99% of the times so I was wondering if it can be done at branch creation automatically.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magit's branch creation commands use `git branch new-branch start-point`, which in some cases automatically sets `start-point` as the upstream. Unfortunately it does not do so in all cases in which it *should* do so IMO.

The relevant documentation is this:

```
       branch.autoSetupMerge
           Tells git branch, git switch and git checkout to set up new
           branches so that git-pull(1) will appropriately merge from the
           starting point branch. Note that even if this option is not set,
           this behavior can be chosen per-branch using the --track and
           --no-track options. The valid settings are: false — no automatic
           setup is done; true — automatic setup is done when the starting
           point is a remote-tracking branch; always —  automatic setup is
           done when the starting point is either a local branch or
           remote-tracking branch. This option defaults to true.
```

So you want to set that variable to `always`.

Additionally you might want to read about the `magit-branch-adjust-remote-upstream-alist` option.

These things are described in more details in the [Branch Commands](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Branch-Commands.html) and [Branch Git Variables](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Branch-Git-Variables.html) sections of the Magit manual. I recommend you also read the surrounding sections.

Comment: thank you very informative answer

Comment: Ok I will make your anwser the accepted one but for the records I needed this:

`(setq magit-branch-adjust-remote-upstream-alist '(("origin/master")))`.

Small caveat, this works only when branching from a remote branch (e.g. from `origin/master` but not from `master`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [Git version 2.35](https://lore.kernel.org/git/xmqqee4x3pij.fsf@gitster.g/), you can set now set `branch.autoSetupMerge = inherit`. It will inherit the tracking configuration from the starting point and set is on your new branch.

That is, if you have a `main` branch that is tracking upstream `origin/main` and you create a new branch starting at `main`, your new branch will be set to track `origin/main` instead of `main` as with `branch.autoSetupMerge = always`.

I got this information from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70714237/646921).